# Creating a function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers both with a save button which essentially does the same thing. So I want to put it in a reusable function that both the controllers can use. I have tried to do this by creating a normal function and passing the model object, as well as $http, but the function is executing before the save button is pressed leading to all the params being set to undefined. What way should I create a function that both these controllers can use?

Here how code looks:

```
app.controller('addCtlr',['$scope','$http','$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location){
        $scope.save = function(){
        var practices = [];
        var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+$scope.location.address.replace(/ /g,"+");


    //If there are practices
        if($scope.days){
            for(dayName in $scope.days){                                                            //Loop through the days object              
                var day = $scope.days[dayName];                                                     //Gets the day pratice object
                practices.push({day: dayName, start_time: day.startTime, end_time: day.endTime});    //Add the pratice object to the practices array
            }
        }
    //Call to get the lat lng and formatted address from Google Map's service
        $http.get(url)
        .then(function(response){
            locJSON = response.data.results[0];                         //The JSON response

            //createing an object to send to the backend to save
            var locObj = {
                name: $scope.location.name,
                address: locJSON.formatted_address,
                location: locJSON.geometry.location,
                cost: $scope.location.cost,
                practices: practices,                                      
                notes: $scope.location.notes
            };

            //Sending using POST since a new object is being created
            $http.post('/api/locations', locObj)
            .then(
                $location.path('/')                                     
            );
        });//*/
    };
    }]);
```

This is how my function looked:

```
function saveLocation(location, days, $http){
    var practices = [];
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location.address.replace(/ /g,"+");


//If there are practices
    if(days){
        for(dayName in days){                                                            //Loop through the days object              
            var day = days[dayName];                                                     //Gets the day pratice object
            practices.push({day: dayName, start_time: day.startTime, end_time: day.endTime});    //Add the pratice object to the practices array
        }
    }
//Call to get the lat lng and formatted address from Google Map's service
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
        locJSON = response.data.results[0];                         

    //createing an object to send to the backend to save
        var locObj = {
            name: location.name,
            address: locJSON.formatted_address,
            location: locJSON.geometry.location,
            cost: location.cost,
            practices: practices,                                      
            notes: location.notes
        };

    //Sending using POST since a new object is being created
        $http.post('/api/locations', locObj)
        .then(
        //$location.path('/')                                     //Redirects the user back to the homepage 
        );
    });
}
```

This is how I was calling the function in the new controller:

```
app.controller('addCtlr',['$scope','$http','$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location){
        $scope.save = saveLocation(location, days, $http);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use service for this. Service is a singleton so will be created only one instance. And You can inject it by a dependency injector to controllers. You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service for your shared functionality and can inject it into your controller like below

```
var app=angular.module('app',[])

app.service('myService',function($http){

  this.saveLocation=function(){
  //Your code
  }

});
```

and then in your controller you can inject it like below

```
app.controller('myController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
 //use myService function to call save functionality
}]);
```

Also if you are using $http, you should keep this in mind that it returns a promise so you need to write all the code which is dependent on the value of this promise in a success callback otherwise your code will run before this callback and you will have undefined values for those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`factory()` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). You can define a set of functions and return them as an object. This object can then be injected within any controller:

```
app.factory('sharedFactory', [function() {
    "use strict";

    return {
        myFunction: function() {
            console.log("sharedFunction");
        }
    };

}]);

app.controller('AnyController', ['sharedFactory', function(sharedFactory) {
    "use strict";

    sharedFactory.myFunction();

}]);
```

Comment: Looks like I cannot use $scope when creating a service. Is there a way to pass the model object as a param to the service?

Comment: You can pass the $scope variable as an argument to any function a service returns. Just define $scope as a function parameter of the returned function in the service and pass the object from the controller.